# Status 500 : System.ServiceModel.ServiceActivationException while calling WCF

Tags: .net, wcf

I am trying to send a string from android client to .NET server. The following is the server side code :-
IService1.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;
using System.Text;

namespace WcfImageUpload
{
    // NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the interface name "IService1" in both code and config file together.
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService1
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "/JsonData",
                RequestFormat  = WebMessageFormat.Json,
                ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, Method = "POST",
                BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest)]
        JsonString SendData(JsonString JsonImage);

        // TODO: Add your service operations here
    }

    // Use a data contract as illustrated in the sample below to add composite types to service operations.
    [DataContract]
    public class JsonString
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string ImageData { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Service1.svc.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;
using System.Text;

namespace WcfImageUpload
{
    // NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the class name "Service1" in code, svc and config file together.
    public class Service1 : IService1
    {
        public JsonString SendData(JsonString JsonImage)
        {
            JsonString jsonStringObject =   new JsonString();
            jsonStringObject.ImageData  =   "ImageData";

            return jsonStringObject;
        }
    }
}
```

Web.config

```
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
        <services>
            <service behaviorConfiguration="Default" name="WcfImageUpload.Service1">
                <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="webBehavior" binding="basicHttpsBinding" contract="WcfImageUpload.IService1" />
                <endpoint contract="IMetadataExchange" binding="mexHttpBinding" address="mex"/>
            </service>
        </services>
        <behaviors>
            <endpointBehaviors>
                <behavior name="webBehavior">
                    <webHttp helpEnabled="true"/>
                </behavior>
            </endpointBehaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior name="Default">
                    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
                </behavior>
                <behavior name="">
                    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
                    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
    </system.serviceModel>
    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

When I test the service using a chrome application called PostMan, we get the following error:-

```
500 System.ServiceModel.ServiceActivationException
```

I am trying to send the json of the format:-

{ImageData: "test string"}

What could be the reason for the error?

Comment: What did the message say and how do you interpret that message?

Comment: Message says:-  500 System.ServiceModel.ServiceActivationException 
I havenot yet interpreted the message, I have no clue what it means or what I should infer from that, if you are an expert kindly pour some light in the issue.

Comment: There's more. Every exception has a stack trace and a message. You are not looking at the full exception. Debug the application and/or enable WCF to transmit fault details (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649234.aspx).

Comment: Now I have resolved that but getting an HTTP 400:Bad Request.

Comment: The same approach applies. Obtain more information. It seems that you do now wish to follow what I said. How do you think you will get help if you don't cooperate? Debugging requires obtaining information. Nobody can just guess the problem all the time.

Comment: Thanks usr, can you please let me know which is to be used for a WCF Rest based POST, <webHttp/> or <enableWebScript/> and why?

Comment: Don't forget, you can't overload WCF methods. I accidentally added a method with a duplicated name and ALL of my WCF calls threw the 500 ServiceActivationException and didn't explicitly highlight the duplicated method name. A 400 usually suggests an error in your config

Answer (score 9):

I just had this problem while running an SP2013 JSOM asynch function

```
clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, OnQuerySuccess), Function.createDelegate(this, OnQueryFail));
```

and solved it via IIS reset.

Just open Windows PowerShell as Administrator and run `iisreset`.